# How can I add a key-value pair to a hash without name?

Tags: ruby

This is my ruby file with hash:

> book.rb

```
class Book
  attr_accessor :title, :author, :language, :classification, :isbn, :book_id, :borrow_status



  def initialize(title, author, language, classification, isbn, book_id, borrow_status)
    @title = title
    @author = author
    @language = language
    @classification = classification
    @isbn = isbn
    @book_id = book_id
    @borrow_status = borrow_status
  end

  def bookid
    @book_id
  end

  def booklist
    @title = @title.split(/ |\_|\-/).map(&:capitalize).join(" ")
    @author = @author.split(/ |\_|\-/).map(&:capitalize).join(" ")
    @language = @language.capitalize
    @isbn.to_s
    @book_id.to_s

    {
        :Title => @title,
        :Author => @author,
        :Language => @language,
        :Classification => @classification,
        :ISBN => @isbn,
        :Book_ID => @book_id,
        :Status => @borrow_status,
    }
  end


end
```

for now, I already have five key-value pair for this hash, they are in ruby file named ***top.rb***:

```
$books1 = Book.new("lonely planet: ireland","damian harper","english","tourism",9781786574459,1,"available")
$books2 = Book.new("ninteen eighty four","george orwell","english","literature",9781374677817, 2,"available")
$books3 = Book.new("japanese in 30 days","naomi ono","japanese","education",9787928365729,3,"available")
$books4 = Book.new("brand famous: how to get everyone talking about your business","linzi boyd","english","business",9780857084903,4,"borrowed")
$books5 = Book.new("SQL in 10 mins","ming zhong, xiaoxia liu","chinese","hi tech",9787115313980,5,"unavailable")
```

and using the method below to output the result:

```
    def status
      bookstatus = gets.chomp.to_s
      if bookstatus == "status"
       puts "Status:" + "\n" + "#{$books1.booklist[:Book_ID]}: #{$books1.booklist[:Title]}: #{$books1.booklist[:Status]}"
       puts "#{$books2.booklist[:Book_ID]}:#{$books2.booklist[:Title]}: #{$books2.booklist[:Status]}"
       puts "#{$books3.booklist[:Book_ID]}:#{$books3.booklist[:Title]}: #{$books3.booklist[:Status]}"
       puts "#{$books4.booklist[:Book_ID]}:#{$books4.booklist[:Title]}: #{$books4.booklist[:Status]}"
       puts "#{$books5.booklist[:Book_ID]}:#{$books5.booklist[:Title]}: #{$books5.booklist[:Status]}"
   else
       puts "error"
end
end
```

For now, I am going to add some more value, I am going to let user enter the information of books (e.g., title = gets.chomp.to_s), and make a new key-value pair for the book added.

As I know, add new key-value pair to ruby is like below:

```
my_hash = {:a => 5}
my_hash[:key] = "value"
```

But, the hash in book.rb does not have any name, I tried to give it a name like

```
book_list = {
        :Title => @title,
        :Author => @author,
        :Language => @language,
        :Classification => @classification,
        :ISBN => @isbn,
        :Book_ID => @book_id,
        :Status => @borrow_status,
    }
```

it will output error.

***My question is, I would like to know how can I add a new key-value pair to the hash in my ruby file, which has no name?***

Thanks.

Comment: The method `booklist` returns the hash, so you can get it as follows: `b = Book.new("Treasure Island", "Bob Stevenson",...);  h = b.booklist`. You may then add a key-value pair: h`[key] = value`. This has nothing to do with the file in which you save your code (unless you want to edit the file to add the key-value pair, which I don't think is your intent

Comment: You'll generate more interest in your SO questions if you state your actual question at the beginning, not at the end after laying down a lot of code. The initial statement may not be complete but it at least gives the reader an idea of what follows. Without that the reader doesn't know what aspects of the code to focus on. Also, you should pair down your code to the essentials. For example, there's no reason for the hash to contain more than, say, two keys, or for `initialize` to have  so many arguments.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the booklist method to this will solve your immediate problem:

```
  def booklist
    @booklist ||= {
        :Title => @title.split(/ |\_|\-/).map(&:capitalize).join(" "),
        :Author => @author.split(/ |\_|\-/).map(&:capitalize).join(" "),
        :Language => @language.capitalize,
        :Classification => @classification,
        :ISBN => @isbn.to_s,
        :Book_ID => @book_id.to_s,
        :Status => @borrow_status,
    }
  end
```

Now you can do `booklist[:Xyz] = 'xyz'`.

The code in your question has so many "Hello world!" -level mistakes, that it appears you still seem to have a bit to learn about Ruby basics, such as using variables, the difference between `@isbn`, `isbn`, `$isbn`, `ISBN`, or `@@isbn`, etc.

There are better "learn ruby" tutorials online than I'm ready to start here, so my answer is probably not very helpful.